# String replace values recursively in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object such as:

```
var json = {
    "title": "Math Symbols: ¬",
    "sections": [
        "The ¬ symbol",
        "¬ and y"       
    ]
};
```

I need to replace all instances of the "¬" character with something that looks like the Mathematical symbol for x: [sample](http://www.fontspace.com/preview/char/9b99267fb6f2f586ce9d5c17985581de.png).

Side note: I can't use that actual symbol (html entity `&#119909;`) because the Arial font i'm using doesn't support it. So I was planning on replacing "¬" with `<span class="math">x</span>` and styling the math class with Times New Roman & italic.

I can't change the Arial Font, and I don't need any other Math symbols - MathML support or the like isn't necessary.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
json = json.replace("¬", "<span class='math'>x</span>");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This converts the JSON into string

```
JSON.stringify(json).replace(/¬/g, "<span class='math'>x</span>")
```

and then you could convert it back to JSON

```
JSON.parse(json)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use replace all or replace no of strings in one statement?

Comment: The `g` means global there, so it would replace all occurrences. I am not sure what you mean with "replace no of strings"? Do you mean stop after a certain number of replacements?